# Calculate without using arrays

Tags: c++, c, arrays

i want to give one number from the user like 3, 
and then give 3 number from user

like this :

```
    int n;
    printf("insert one number");
    scanf("%d", n);

    int a;
    for(int i = 1; i <=n; i++){
          scanf("%d", a);
    }
```

**and without using Array calculate this...
this is very important that using array is ban**

Σa[i]a[j] (i≠j)

input example:

*3
  1  2  3*

calculate this

*1x2 + 1x3 + 2x1 + 2x3 + 3x1 + 3x2*

and output 22

sorry for my bad english, can anyone help me?

Comment: This looks like a solution request. Write some code first :)

Comment: You have to store the input values somewhere... as it is now you are overwriting 'a' every time (except for the bug)

Comment: Are pointers + `malloc` allowed? (As they are (in C) different from arrays...)

Comment: You can do that without storing the numbers, but you have to think how. This is more a math problem than a programming problem. To solve it, think: what does that sum of products look like? (hint: what happens when you multiply a sum of numbers with itself: (a+b+c)*(a+b+c)? In what terms does it differ?)

Comment: @Kninnug The same can be said for `new`, which would let you stay in the realm of C++.

Comment: Thanks a lot,i think i found that,thank for your answer.

Comment: @memo1288 Thanks a lot,i think i found that,thank for your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to attempt to answer this without actually giving you the answer:

Since the first number of your input is the number of values you want to read in, you need to store that separately and use it to create a loop.

Your loop (using your example input) will need to compute:

> (1*2 + 1*3) + (2*1 + 2*3) + (3*1 + 3*2)

Which brings it down to what memo1288 was alluding to:  figuring out the math component.

Answer (score 1):

Let's do some math. The original expression, in its complete form, based on the example you gave, is:

f(a, n) = Σa[i]a[j] (i < n, j < n, j ≠ i)

= Σa[i] (i < n) Σa[j] (j < n, j ≠ i)

When we replace n with n+1 we get:

f(a, n+1) = Σa[i] (i < n+1) Σa[j] (j < n + 1, j ≠ i)

= Σa[i] (i < n) Σa[j] (j < n + 1, j ≠ i) + a[n] Σa[j] (j < n + 1, j ≠ n)

= Σa[i] (i < n) Σa[j] (j < n + 1, j ≠ i) + a[n] Σa[j] (j < n)

= Σa[j] (j < n + 1) Σa[i] (i < n, j ≠ i) + a[n] Σa[j] (j < n)

= Σa[j] (j < n) Σa[i] (i < n, j ≠ i) + a[n] Σa[j] (j < n) + a[n] Σa[j] (j < n)

= f(a, n) + 2a[n] Σa[i] (i < n)

In other words, the value of the calculation for n numbers is equal to the value of the calculation for n-1 numbers, plus 2 * the nth number multiplied by the sum of all the previous numbers.

It should be pretty easy to see how you can do this without using an array. You just need to keep track of the running sum of numbers, and the running value of the calculation.

I'll let you write the actual code, since this is clearly a homework question, but that should be plenty of information to get you started.

Comment: Close.  His original post stated that `i != j`, not `i < j` (which changes the result).

Comment: @ZacHowland You're right; fix'd. You'll notice the result is just twice what it was before, which should be intuitively obvious (because for any i and j, i≠j, the sum will include both a[i]a[j] and a[j]a[i])